# React render API using hooks

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I need to display random quote from API using React hooks `useState` and `useEffect`.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
const API =
 "https://gist.githubusercontent.com/camperbot/5a022b72e96c4c9585c32bf6a75f62d9/raw/e3c6895ce42069f0ee7e991229064f167fe8ccdc/quotes.json";
const App = () => {
  const [quote, setQuote] = useState({
    quotes: [],
    index: 0,
  });
  useEffect(() => {
    fetch(API)
      .then((res) => {
        return res.json();
      })
      .then((quote) => {
        setQuote(quote);
        console.log(quote.quotes[0].quote); // prints quote
        console.log(quote.index); // prints undefined
      });
  }, []);
  const getRandomIndex = () => {
    setQuote((previosState) => {
      return {
        ...previosState,
        index: Math.floor(Math.random() * quote.quotes.length),
      };
    });
  };
  return (
    <>
      <p>this is quote: "{quote.quotes[index]}"</p>
    </>
  );
};
export default App;
```

In the `useEffect` hook it prints correct quote, but it prints undefined for index.
Could you help me to print random quote here

```
<p>this is quote: "{quote.quotes[index]}"</p>
```

after index was randomly generated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you're going in the right way. Just some slight changes to make it work better.

1. I separate `quotes` and `index` because the response is an object that has the "quotes" field, and not the `index` field. Your `setQuote(quote);` will set `index` to undefined.
2. Each item in `quotes` is an object which has `quote` and `author` and if `quotes` is empty, [0] will be undefined, that's why I used optional chaining (`?.`) in `quotes[index]?.quote`.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
const API =
  "https://gist.githubusercontent.com/camperbot/5a022b72e96c4c9585c32bf6a75f62d9/raw/e3c6895ce42069f0ee7e991229064f167fe8ccdc/quotes.json";

const getRandomInRange = (min, max) => {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min) + min);
};

const App = () => {
  const [quotes, setQuotes] = useState([]);
  const [index, setIndex] = useState(0);

  useEffect(() => {
    fetch(API)
      .then((res) => {
        return res.json();
      })
      .then((data) => {
        setQuotes(data.quotes);
      });
  }, []);

  const setRandomIndex = () => {
    setIndex(getRandomInRange(0, quotes.length));
  };

  return (
    <>
      <p>this is quote: {quotes[index]?.quote}</p>
      <button onClick={setRandomIndex}>Another</button>
    </>
  );
};
export default App;
```

Comment: could you please explain me more detailed why you used `?.` operator and how it works?

Comment: `quotes[index].quote` means you want to access `quote` from `index`th of `quotes`.
In case `quotes` = [] and `index` = 5, `quotes[index]` will be undefined and an error is thrown at `quotes[index].quote`. To avoid it, we must check if `quotes[index] && quotes[index].quote`. And `quotes[index]?.quote` is short-hand for the expression. More info here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining

Answer (score 1):

Hey I adjusted your `quote` state structure to be an array holding all the quotes that way you will not need to set random `index`, we can easily load a random quote based on array index. See the updated `App.js` here (I updated some of the namings and removed the `getRandomIndex` since that's redundant:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
const API =
  'https://gist.githubusercontent.com/camperbot/5a022b72e96c4c9585c32bf6a75f62d9/raw/e3c6895ce42069f0ee7e991229064f167fe8ccdc/quotes.json';
const App = () => {
  const [quotes, setQuotes] = useState([]);
  useEffect(() => {
    fetch(API)
      .then((res) => {
        return res.json();
      })
      .then((quote) => {
        setQuotes(quote.quotes);
      });
  }, []);

  return (
    <>
      {console.log(quotes)}
      <p>
        this is quote: "
        {quotes.length !== 0
          ? quotes[Math.floor(Math.random() * quotes.length)].quote
          : 'Loading'}
        "
      </p>
    </>
  );
};
export default App;
```

Also this line of code in your question logs `undefined` because `quote` references to the data coming from API and it does not have `index` property.

```
console.log(quote.index); // prints undefined because quote is from fetch and it does not have index property
```

Comment: it doesn't work, could you fix it

Comment: It should work  I just did not add the `import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";` on the first line since it's the most basic thing and I thought you would know that. I updated the code in my response anyways, if you see error let me know what is the issue so I know what is wrong?

Comment: No problem at all :)